# How to execute methods from a running service from broadcast?

Tags: android, service, communication, broadcast

on a broadcast I want to call a non static method from Service XYZ. The Service is start by the receiver on boot.
Has someone a idea to run methods from this running service?
One solution in this forum is to make the method static and use a singleton pattern to execute. But is there another method? Maybe with a binder?

//EDIT for example i have the following clases:

```java
public class MyService extends Service{
   .....
   public void method(){
      //TODO
   }
}
```

```java
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
   .....
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentAction=intent.getAction();
    if(intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){  
        //start service
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

    }
    else{ 
     //TODO call method() in MyService
    }
}
```

how can i call the method `method()`? I know that i can cast with `context.getSystemService()` system services. But how can i get my own service object?

greetings

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. When you broadcast from a service you can listen to that broadcast in any active activity - when you receive the broadcast you can execute whatever you want in your activity. If you're trying to run a method in your service when it receives a broadcast, then you can do that as well without a singleton.

Comment: my service and my broadcast are in Independent clases. In the update i have one example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an action string to your intent using `setAction` in the intent that launches the `Service`. In your service's `onStartcommand` you can extract the intent's action, and based off that you can execute the method in your service.

You will always send commands to your service using `startService` this will not launch your service twice. It will either get started once, or the new intent is sent to the service.

So, in your on boot completed section you should set the intent action to whatever you want, and start the service - you can remove the else block completely.

In your Service implement the `onStartCommand`, extract the intent's action, and based off that action you can just execute your method.