# How can I invoke a method of a service class from a broadcastReceiver ?

Tags: android, service, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm implementing a broadcast receiver to check connectivity. I want to invoke method of the **service** from the **onReceive** method of the receiver.

How I can invoke method of a service from a receiver ?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if ((intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
            || (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)))) {
        boolean status = NetworkUtil.isOnline(context);

        if (status) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);


            //  Here I want to invoke a method in the service to consume api and check new results ;

            updateAllWidgets(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, "Network change   " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340168/how-to-execute-methods-from-a-running-service-from-broadcast) This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem by following those steps:

1. I identify the tasks of the service (consume api , store data
   ...) and when they are done I stop the service .
2. When the receiver notify me that the Wifi is disabled , I stop
   the current service and when It notify me that the Wifi is enabled,
   I start  the service again to redo all the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to start long time operation that doesn't need to perform UI operation, *You can use `IntentService` instead of `Service`, as `Service` do run on `MainThread`*.

Say for example your service is like -

```
public class MyActionService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Data will be available in intent
        // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
    }
}
```

You can start service using

```
startService(new Intent(context, MyActionService.class));
```

As soon as you start service, your `onHandleIntent()` will get called, If you are willing do any operation, this is the place you do

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

1. Create BroadcastReciever

   ```
                       public class NetworkInfoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                           NetworkInfoListener infoListener;

                           @Override
                           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                               if (null != intent) {
                                   try {
                                       infoListener = (NetworkInfoListener) context;
                                       if (infoListener != null) {
                                           infoListener.onNetWorkStatusChange(LegionUtils.isOnline(context));
                                       }
                                   } catch (Exception e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }
   ```

   2.Create Interface

   ```
                   public interface NetworkInfoListener {
                       void onNetWorkStatusChange(boolean isConnected);
                   }
   ```

   3. Register Reciever in your activity onResume()

      ```
                public static void doRegisterConnectivityReceiver(NetworkInfoReceiver receiver, Context context) {
                      try {
                          if (receiver != null && context != null) {
                              IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
                              context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
                          }
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
      ```
   4. When you implements NetworkInfoListener in your activity the below overide method will call when network change

      ```
                @Override
              public void onNetWorkStatusChange(boolean isConnected) {
                  LegionUtils.doUpdateNetworkStatus(ShiftDropSucessActivity.this,        offlineTv, isConnected);
              }
      ```
2. Unregister BroadcastReciver in your activity

   ```
     public static void doUnRegisterConnectivityReceiver(Context context, NetworkInfoReceiver networkInfoReciver) {
           try {
               if (networkInfoReciver != null && context != null) {
                   context.unregisterReceiver(networkInfoReciver);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   ```